# How do you make SAS toolbar available to ALL windows?

Tags: toolbar, sas, dm, display-manager

I am using SAS 9.1 and wish to make my toolbar available regardless of which window is in 'focus' (eg log, editor, output).

My code looks like this:

```
libname temp678 "\\MyDrive\Team Autoexec";
dm "toolload bar temp678.profile.MycustomToolbar";
libname temp678 clear;
```

However when I run it, it only gets applied to the Log window!  I've read somewhere that SWITCHING needs to be turned off, but this seems like it may have been a V6.1 option and can't find it in Base SAS windowing environment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a TOOLSWITCH command in 9.1 but I don't think that will do what you want here.  Unless someone is aware of a specific option to do what you want, I'd suggest just duplicating your additional buttons on both the log and editor toolbars.